# unable to install joomla 3.1.5 in my pc

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.1

I am using joomla 3.1.5.

While installing joomla on my localhost, installation goes to infinite loop showing only Creating database tables process.

Can any one help me in this.

Do I need to change anything in php.ini or anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change below settings value:

```
max_execution_time = 30 => 100
post_max_size = 8M => 50M
upload_max_filesize = 2M => 50M
```

And then try again.